# people passing a bridge (a proof for a greedy algorithm)

Tags: algorithms, proof-writing

**the problem**

some people are passing a bridge . each one takes a different time to pass .

assume the people are sorted by their passing time increasingly .

these are the conditions of passing the bridge :

1. only 2 (or less) people can pass the bridge at the same time in the same direction.
2. the speed of the two people passing is the same as the slower one .
3. it is night and there is only one flashlight .
4. the people passing the bridge must carry the flashlight .
5. the flashlight cannot be thrown over the bridge. so it must be carried back to the other end of the bridge .

**My Greedy solution**

the obvious solution seems to be using the fastest guy to pass every one to the other end ; and come back for the rest .

**The proof**
i tried to prove it like my text book CLRS :

> 1.Cast the optimization problem as one in which we make a choice and are
>   left with one subproblem to solve.
>
> 2.Prove that there is always an optimal solution to the original problem
>   that makes the greedy choice, so that the greedy choice is always
>   safe.
>
> 3.Demonstrate optimal substructure by showing that, having made the greedy choice, what remains is a subproblem with the property that if
>   we combine an optimal solution to the subproblem with the greedy
>   choice we have made, we arrive at an optimal solution to the original
>   problem.

i tried something like this :

if we assume the set of all people in the start is $P$ and the set of all people in the destination is $D$ and $O(x)$ is the function that gives the optimum time by getting the set of people and people $p_i$ and $p_j$ are chosen to pass the bridge and $d_k$ is chosen to return the light then and $d_k \in D\cup \{p_i , p_j\}$ :

$$O(P) = Max( t(p_i) , t(p_j) ) + t(d_k) + O(P-\{p_i , p_j\} \cup {d_k})$$

where $t(p_i)$ is the time it takes for person $p_i$ to pass.

now i have to assume i have an optimal solution $OS$ and show that i can replace the greedy choice instead of the choice the $OS$ has made .

i do not know how to proceed further .

**Edit**

there seems to be a counterexample for the method . inspired by Arthur.

in a revised version of what he said (with fastest person returning the light ) . with four people we would get . $t(p_1)+3t(p_2)+t(p_4)$ . and with greedy solution we would get $2t(p_1)+t(p_2)+t(p_3)+t(p_4)$ . comparing them if $t(p_3) + t(p_1)$ is grater than $2t(p2)$ then the greedy gives a wrong answer .

Comment: It might be faster for the two fastest to go over, one of them go back with the flash light, then the two slowest pass, and finally the second quick person goes back with the light.

Comment: you forgot to take the light with the two slowest

Comment: is there a greedy algorithm for this . what about a dynamic programming algorithm

Comment: Maybe be greedy for something else, such as try to maximize $\min t[D]-\max t[P]$ or something similar?